# Cannot extract custom HTTP request headers

Tags: http, iis, http-headers, isapi, custom-headers

Is it mandatory to add prefix like `http_ , x_ or header_` to custom headers which we want to include in http requests?

I am using `GetServerVariable` API to extract the value of custom Http headers sent in HTTP request and it doesn't seem to extract values not starting with above prefixes. i am on Windows 10 and IIS Version 10.

Any hints?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory in the HTTP protocol. It might be that the *API* that you are using has a specific convention for prefixes.

Comment: Can you let me know the API to extract custom HTTP header on Windows? Something equivalent to GetServerVariable

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below code to get the value of a custom header from a Web API request; it extends the HttpRequestMessage class:

Assuming you have a HttpRequestMessage object, you can call it as such:

```
var customHeaderValue = request.GetHeaderValue("Custom-Header");
```